# add anchor text on url PHP

Tags: php, html

after click the submit button on my form, how do I add the anchor "#work" in the url without reloading the page?

example: www.test.it/#work

i use `header('Location: #work');` but refresh my page.

Update:

I use "jessica" solution: 
I think the page is reloaded

But don't work, ca see here: http://www.substellar.it/ftende/contatti/

I think the page is reloaded

Comment: why not add #work to the submit action?

Comment: `<form action="submit-link-o-this-url#work" >` Why don't you try this?

Comment: @Dagon : I deleted the answer. You got it right first.

Comment: sorry man its cool. i actually assume there's a reason not to do this. as it seems so obvious. but maybe that's just me

Comment: It's okay. You hurt my feelings :P

Comment: @user1012181 If neither of you wants it, I'll answer it.

Comment: No problem, Go ahead :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify the URL without reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 1):

Just add #work to the action in form for it to show up in the link.

```
<form action = "url#work">
```

Comment: if your lucky the OP may turn up one day and accept it

Comment: @Dagon I can't resist. If *you're lucky. :)

Comment: i hope you realised that one was deliberate

Comment: don't work, there is a way to make this in php? the page is reloaded

Comment: @Eugenio If you want to use this in between php tags you have to echo it out.

Comment: i hope you like down votes because this is how you get down votes

Comment: @Dagon Come on. Can't you take a little light humor? -.-

Comment: i haven't tested, but won't this reload the page?

Comment: @Pamblam That's kind of the point of a form though, isn't it? You can't submit a form without reloading the page.

Comment: Jessica that was the point of a former back in 1995, these days we have ajax. Regardless, OP specified that he doesn't want to reload.